# How to send coupon code in new user registration email template?

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.7

I have a requirement when ever anew user register to my site.I want to send the coupon code to the customer with registration email?

I followed following tutorial for the same. [Tutorial](http://prasadoturkar.blogspot.in/2014/03/send-promo-code-to-new-registered.html)

But I am getting a blank email containing nothing.

I used following in my config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <customer_register_success>
            <coupon_observers>
                <coupon>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Mynamespace_Coupon_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>sendCoupon</method>
                </coupon>
            </coupon_observers>
        </customer_register_success>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Comment: Is it a unique coupon code? If it's a general code, you can add it to your registration confirmation mail.

Comment: It should Take from Magento admin shopping cart price rule.

Comment: Is it the one and the same price rule for all customers?

Comment: Yes same coupon code will go to every customer for on time use only

Comment: Check my answer below. That's the most simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the coupon code and set setting 'Uses per Customer' to 1.
Go to `system -> transactional emails` and change / add mailtemplate 'new account' and add your created coupon code to this mail.